# is there a way to combine Qt-Creator + Boost Library?

Tags: c++, qt, boost, qt-creator

I was wondering if there was a way to use the boost library in Qt-creator (the IDE version of Qt).

Thanks,
A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Qt Creator doesn't require the use of Qt in your application.  If you don't want to link to any Qt libraries, or run MOC on any header files (which you only need to do for subclasses of QObject), then just do [`QT -= core gui`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html#declaring-qt-libraries) (to get rid of Qt libraries from the link command. Perhaps `QT =` would work, too), and don't specify any [`HEADERS`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html#variables).

Good luck, post back if it works.

Answer (score 3):

Boost is not just one library, it's a collection of them. Some are just header files, in those cases you just need to #include them in your source as normal. Which Boost functionality do you require?